# Should i rethrow an interrupt when catching an InterruptedException in the catch block when doing a KafkaTemplate.send?

Tags: spring-kafka

To send a record to a topic using `KafkaTemplate` which is configured as a bean like so:

```
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

, one would do:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate;
...
SendResult<Object, Object> sendResult = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, object).get();
```

and would catch the `InterruptedException` & `ExecutionException` by wrapping the above in a try/catch block like so

```
try {
  SendResult<Object, Object> sendResult = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, object).get();
  if (sendResult.getRecordMetadata() != null && sendResult.getRecordMetadata().hasOffset()) {
     //some code
  } else {
     //some code
  }
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {     
  logger.error("An error has occurred: ", e);
}
```

Recently, i have learnt that the best practice when an interrupted exception has occurred would be to re-throw it in the catch block like so:

```
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {     
  logger.error("An error has occurred: ", e);
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

(1) Is this recommended in the `KafkaTemplate` context? I would tend to think no, because all the examples i am seeing are without the interrupt being re-thrown.
(2) If yes, what is the *benefit*?
(3) Is there any *downside* if the interrupt is not re-thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic interrupt handling and has nothing to do with Kafka.

> `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`

Yes, that is the best practice.

You are not "rethrowing" the interrupt there, you are setting the interrupt bit so that, if a downstream interruptible operation is performed on the thread, it too will be interrupted.

There is a big downside if you don't set the interrupt bit. When a thread is interrupted, usually, the application wants the thread to exit what it's doing.

Consider:

```java
public void method2() {

    ...
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // ignore
    }

}

public void method1() throws InterruptedException {

    ...
    method2();
    System.out.println("method2 returned ok");
    Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);

}
```

The thread will hang and never exit because you "ate" the interrupt.

However, you should **not** do this in a multi-catch:

```java
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {     
  logger.error("An error has occurred: ", e);
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

This would set the interrupt bit with both exceptions, not just the `InterruptedException`.

Comment: Short, sweet and simple(well not _simple_, as i had to dig deeper into interrupt, but worth the effort) example & explanation Gary. Thanks!